# PowerPoint shuts down when I paste code in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Whenever I try to paste code in PowerPoint VBA, the program just shuts down and reboots a recovery version of the open file - no error message or anything. Has anyone experienced anything similar and know of a quick fix?

(I haven't tried a fresh install of Office. It's on my work computer and a fresh install would entail me having to deliver my computer to IT for the better part of a day which I would very much like to avoid for such a trivial issue.)

Comment: What if you just try to write code, not paste anything?

Comment: What are you pasting from? Some blog post? Sometimes that would include hidden characters like `&nbsp;`, that could cause problems with the code. Consider *typing* code instead of pasting it.

Comment: Writing code works fine, only pasting that creates issues. Doesn't matter where I copy from. If I copy part of something I have written in one sub to paste into another sub same thing happens.

Comment: Try running an Office repair, Online Repair ios the most effective: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b